# Python : Open file and take value from it and pass in to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

```
data={'name':"1.1.1.1",'subnet'="1.1.1.1/32",'id'=3,'env'="PROD"}
```

Now only changing key is name and subnet, id and env remain same.
while passing name and subnet  value must be inside "".

input file like be
1.1.1.1  1.1.1.1/32

```
with open("file1.txt") as f:
     for i in f:
         value_string=str(i)
         data={'name':'+value_string+','subnet'="1.1.1.1/32",'id'=3,'env'="PROD"}
         pprint(data)
```

But its doesnt have value in "" and how i can pass value in subnet.

Comment: You don't seem to be using your value string anywhere. I would have expected you to split it by spaces and then use that result. to store into your name and subnet properties.

Comment: If you see I'm using here in code  'name':'+value_string+' but not sure how make string with "1.1.1.1" rather than just 1.1.1.1.     And I got your point that I can spilt and use it at name and subnet.

Comment: based on what I undesrstood data is a .txt file like these: 
'name':"1.1.1.1"
'subnet'="1.1.1.1/32"
'id'=3
'env'="PROD"

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you're looking for something like

```
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ip, subnet = line.strip().split(None, 1)
        data = {"name": ip, "subnet": subnet, "id": 3, "env": "PROD"}
        pprint(data)
```

Comment: yes it works but my bad I have not given the full picture so basically this is my whole code

Answer (score -1):

Please see my solution below:

```
data = dict()

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data['name'], data['subnet'], data['id'], data['env'] =  line.split(' ')[0], line.split(' ')[1], '3', 'PROD'
```